# cannot dump data by using python ./manage.py dumpdata app

Tags: python, django, fixture

I created an app in a Django project. For testing purpose, I would like to create fixture files. I found that I can dump my database in order to create fixture automatically if it already has data. I want to use a fixture, so I used the command `python ./manage.py dumpdata app`, but it returned a list of a ton of `\x02`. But if I use `python ./manage.py auth` it runs perfectly. Any idea why my `dumpdata` shows only `\x02`.

Thanks in advance.

I attached screenshot as following link:

http://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~fon/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Screenshot.png

Comment: what does `python manage.py dumpdata app | head` show?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely.  When you dump the data you need to store it in a fixture.  Check out this blog post:
http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2008/09/28/use-django-fixtures-to-automatically-load-data-when-you-install-an-app/

Basically do something like this (replace [app_name] with the name of your app):

```
python manage.py dumpdata [app_name] > [app_name]/fixtures/initial_data.json
```

You will probably need to create the fixtures directory for your app.

When you run python manage.py syncdb it will automatically look for fixtures in the location [app_name]/fixtures/initial_data.json

Also, if you don't need the ./ when you type python.  i.e. you can write

```
python manage.py ...
```

rather than

```
python ./manage.py ...
```

Comment: I already did "python manage.py dumpdata app --format=json --indent=8 > app/fixtures/ffixture.json" It doesn't work at all.It shown nothing in file and print only '/x01/x02' something like that on screen.

Comment: Try creating a really simple app with one model with one charfield.  Populate something in the admin and and run the dumpdata command again and see if it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you should run `python manage.py dumpdata app > datafile` and then load data with `python manage.py loaddata datafile`

Answer (score 0):

```
import dump

dump.accept(var, 'file eg: text.txt')
```

Comment: I get "ImportError: No module named dump", where can I found/install that module?